# Identifying data files

Tags: database, file

I have the job of doing a data conversion. So I am trying to find an odbc driver to help with the conversion. The problem is: I can't figure out in what database the files were created in. So I don't know what odbc driver to look for.

Here is what I have:
The data is stored in .k and .d files. I believe the files were created in linux. When I open them in notepad++, I can see some data here and there, but it is interspersed with special characters. On my computer they appear as japanese kanji characters.

Can anyone shed some light on this? Or does anyone maybe have a suggestion on how to go about converting these files?

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Have you tried looking at the files with a hex editor?  If the files were created by a C/C++ program and not by any specific database program, you will need to treat the file content like flat files.  The binary data might contain information such as row length or column count.

Comment: Sorry for the extremely late reply tgolisch. We had to push another project to try and get it finished.
I have looked at the files in a hexeditor, so far it still makes little sense to me. There seems to be 6 different files for what I assume is each database/table. There is a .k, .d, .f, .g, .q and .r version of each file. The .k file is the largest, but contains a LOT of zeros and seemingly random numbers/values. I am not quite sure how to approach this.

Comment: Can you get your hands on the original program & source code?